# Dynamic jQuery code to equal div's height?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code which sets all `div.column` to have the same height

```
jQuery(function($){


$(document).ready(function(){

    // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
    $('.container').each(function(){  
      
      // Cache the highest
      var highestBox = 0;
      
      // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
      $('.column', this).each(function(){
        
        // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
        if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
          highestBox = $(this).height(); 
        }
      
      });  
            
      // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest 
      $('.column',this).height(highestBox);
                    
    }); 

});


});
```

However, the `div.column` contains expandable elements inside and this code is just executed when the page is loaded.

Is there any way to re-execute the same code with every single click in the page?

Comment: don't use jquery - use flexbox css, it will do it automatically - have a google, equal height columns flex

Comment: @Pete thanks, is 'flexbox' cross browser?

Comment: Flexbox is really well supported nowdays: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: It has pretty much full browser support in modern browsers - you just need to watch out for some quirks in ie and safari if you use nested flexbox